# AlertDialogBox showing even though never called kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, android-alertdialog

I'm making an android app, and requesting permission to read storage.

Here is the code to request the permission:

```
private fun checkPermission():Boolean {
        return checkSelfPermission(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

private fun toast(text: String){
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

}
private fun setupPermissions() {
    if (!checkPermission()) {
        var requestCode = 7
        requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), requestCode)
        if (!checkPermission()) {
            toast("Permissions not granted")

            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
            builder.setTitle("Permissions were denied.")
            builder.setMessage("You must allow MyApp access to your files to continue.\n\nNote: If you clicked \"Don't ask again,\" you'll have to enable the permission in settings")
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
                setupPermissions()
            }
            builder.setNeutralButton("EXIT") { _, _ ->
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "You cancelled the dialog.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
            dialog.show()
        }
        else{
            toast("Permissions granted")
        }
    }


}
```

The problem is that it requests the permissions, but you can see the AlertDialog box under it, even though it shouldn't have been called yet:

[Screenshot of app when it launches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CM52.jpg)
(It says "Don't ask again" because I've tried it multiple times)

It seems like it's running `requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), requestCode)`, and without waiting for the user to select Allow or Deny, it shows the dialog box.

Why is this happening? Any help is appreciated, as I am new to kotlin

Comment: So when do you want the `Dialog` to appear?

Comment: I want it to appear if the permission request was denied.

Comment: So you don't want it to appear immediately if they haven't given permission. You want the Permission box to appear. Then if they click deny in the Permission box, you make the `Dialog`? Is that right?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Ok so what you have to do is take out your code for making the `Dialog` and have that code run when the user clicks **DENY**. In order to do that, you would have to detect whether or not they have accepted or granted the permission after showing them the permission box.

Comment: But that's what the second `if(!checkpermission())` is supposed to do

Comment: I'm currently writing an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the `Dialog` appears immediately is because you are checking whether to create it or not after requesting the permission.

The second `if (!checkPermission())` doesn't make a difference because the permission change does not happen instantaneously. You can try the following steps:

1. **Remove the code to make your `Dialog` in `setUpPermissions()`.**
2. **Copy and paste the code below:**

   ```
   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
       super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
       if (!checkPermission()) {
           toast("Permissions not granted")

           val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
           builder.setTitle("Permissions were denied.")
           builder.setMessage("You must allow MyApp access to your files to continue.\n\nNote: If you clicked \"Don't ask again,\" you'll have to enable the permission in settings")
           builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
               setupPermissions()
           }
           builder.setNeutralButton("EXIT") { _, _ ->
               Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "You cancelled the dialog.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
           }
           val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
           dialog.show()
       }
       else{
           toast("Permissions granted")
       }
   }
   ```

What this should do is after the result of the `requestPermission()` has taken place, it should check the permission. Then, if it was not granted, it will make the `Dialog`.

Let me know if this works or if you run into any errors since I didn't get to test it myself.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, with a few modifications: https://pastebin.com/raw/bGH1Xw6N